# How do I determine if mobile context override?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mobile

In my MVC4 app, I sometimes am doing this for some users:

`HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(BrowserOverride.Mobile)`

How do I determine if the user is using an overridden context or using the default context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var hasBrowserOverride = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".ASPXBrowserOverride"] != null;
```

or even better

```
 var isOverriden = Request.UserAgent == HttpContext.GetOverriddenUserAgent();
```